# RDP troubleshooting, past checking port 3389

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp

I have some hosts that get into a bad state.  The consistent symptom is that RDP connections to it hang right after handshake.   It is listening on 3389, so telnetting to that port doesn't help me.

I'm looking for some kind of command tool that actually will perform that connection.

I've tried [rdpy](https://github.com/citronneur/rdpy), but it seems to be GUI based and requires PyQT

Answer (score -1):

Found something that seems to work

https://github.com/dnozay/check_x224

Comment: Please **don't** provide link only answers.